# how to use OR in jquery

Tags: jquery

1st i would like to thanks all who view this and special thanks for those who answer this.

today, i tested this out but it not working, so just want to know how should this code.
multiple "OR" in one line

```
$("input[name='ABC']or[name='DEF']or[name='GHI']or[name='JKL']").click(function (){ 
    //do something
});
```

or even put else for it like...

```
$("input[name='ABC'][name='DEF'][name='GHI'][name='JKL']").click(function (){ 
    //do something
}else{
    //do something else
});
```

i know both code is invalid, so is that possible to code in that way? so far i code it all one by one, so my coding is very long.

Answer (score 2):

Use **comma** to separate elements like jhonraymos suggested.

I would suggest you to add a **class** for all these elements

```
<input type="text" name="ABC" class="special" />
<input type="text" name="DEF" class="special" />
<input type="text" name="GHI" class="special" />
<input type="button" name="JKL" class="special" />
...
```

And then

```
$('input.special').click(function() {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: i know this way, but not lucky that all my input is randomly generated, so i cant specify it for the class. anyway thanks

Comment: you can still add a class for these elements WHILE they are being generated, and then use live method $(document).on('click', 'input.special', function() { // do something });

Answer (score 1):

you could use the multiple selector http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use or by placing `,` between them

Use this

```
$("input[name='ABC'],[name='DEF'],[name='GHI'],[name='JKL']").click(function (){ 
//do something
});
```

Comment: ok, i will try the comman later, never think about this way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted a more customized solution you could use something like:

```
$("input[name]").filter(function() { return this.getAttribute('name').search(/^(ABC|DEF)$/) > 0;});
```

Which you could then wrap in a function to abstract as needed and make the client code more readable.

I'd suggest something like:

```
var attrPattern = function(attrName, pattern) {
  return function() {
    return this.getAttribute(attrName).search(pattern) > 0;
  }
}
```

Which you could then call with

```
$("input[name"]).filter(attrPattern("name", pattern));
```